# File doesn't update after cmd file is run

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I started coding a program with cmd that changes the name of the file once opened. I have 3 files, `tr.txt` that saves a random number, the error file `error.txt` and the varying-name file, eg `532.cmd`.

Their contents:
`532.cmd`

```
echo "" > error.txt
set rand123=%random%
set /p oldrand=<tr.txt 2>> error.txt
rename %oldrand%.cmd %rand123%.cmd 2>> error.txt
echo %rand123% >tr.txt 2>> error.txt
```

and
`tr.txt`

```
532
```

The bug is somewhere in the echo function, because if i move it on the 2nd line, the rest wont run. The `tr.txt` file doesn't update, and the `error.txt` doesn't show any errors. I'm new to cmd and i don't know much, so any help/advice is welcome

Comment: So you try to rename `532<space>.cmd`, because you are writing a number plus a space to `tr.txt`. Change to `(echo %rand123%) > tr.txt`

Comment: So you're trying to get the batch file to rename itself with a random name. Please explain a **good** reason for this.

Comment: @Compo just for fun tbh, i did it anyway

Comment: If it was for fun, there would be no need to ask others to do it! Anyhow, please submit your answer in the answer area, or delete your question, it has no future purpose here without an accepted answer.